# Exiting a for loop using a conditional

Tags: javascript, control-flow

I had a problem which was that I was using a loop e.g

```
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
if(i === 3){
    // go to the next iteration of the loop
}
console.log(i)
```

}

and I was struggling to see how to get to the next iteration. I tried a "return" statement but this came up with the error "illegal return statement" and having done a quick search on the forums the answer was not obvious, so I thought I'd log it here so that next time I can find it easier.

Comment: I recommend to bookmark this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#continue_statement

Answer (score 0):

Having looked through the MDN docs, what IU actually wanted was a **"continue"** statement which short-circuits the rest of the code in the block and goes straight to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write a continue keyword in for loop to goto next loop,

```
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    if(i === 3){
        continue;
    }
    console.log(i)
}
```

> Note: choose **let** judiciously, it can also be used with **var** as it is having a function scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the rest of code in current iteration and get to next one, `continue;`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

If you want to exit loop completely, use `break;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: In addition, if you want to break out of a nested loop then use an empty "return;"